# need help,ubuntu theme problem

Tags: 14.04, unity, themes

I am a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS user and everything was working fine,until I miss clicked some button or may have deleted a file,the Ubuntu currently looks weird,and mostly unusable.
want help for it to be corrected.

The tools bars in the top can't be seen unless clicked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Ambiance'
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme 'Ambiance'
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the gear cog that is on the top-right corner on the screen.
2. Select "System Settings" from the menu.
3. On the system settings, click on "Appearance"
4. In the bottom-right of this window, you have a theme selector, select any theme on it.
5. Select "Ambiance"